# CakePHP -- conditions ignored when using paginate() twice in a single action

Tags: cakephp, conditional-statements, pagination

I have a photoblog built on CakePHP 2.0 with a data structure that looks like:

`POSTS <-habtm-> TAGS <-habtm-> IMAGES`

I am building an AJAX-based feature to find all blog posts and images that match a given tag. Page 1 of Posts and page 1 of Images are loaded into adjacent panels when a tag is first selected. After that, they can be paged through independently. For the most part this is working fine, except when I am fetching the initial pages of data.

I am using `paginate()` twice in the first action -- once to get my Posts and a second time to get the Images. The problem is that the conditions I assign to `paginate()` for the second model in the sequence are completely ignored. Individually they both work fine, and switching their order has confirmed it's a sequence-dependent problem for me, rather than restricted to one of the models or the other.

I've searched to see if anyone else has encountered similar problems in the past, but this is either an unusual design choice on my part or I'm not finding the right search query.

My basic `$paginate` array is declared as follows in my `TagsController.php`:

```
public $paginate = array(
    "PostsTag" => array(
        "limit" => 4,
        "order" => "Post.id DESC",
        "contain" => array(
            "Tag",
            "Post" => array("fields" => array(
                "id", "title", "created"))
        ),
        "group" => array("Post.id")
    ),
    "ImagesTag" => array(
        "limit" => 4,
        "order" => "Image.id DESC",
        "contain" => array(
            "Tag",
            "Image" => array("fields" => array(
                "id", "title", "url", "created", "gallery"))
        ),
        "group" => array("Image.id")
    )
);
```

From my main search action I call two private functions:

```
$posts = $this->post_pagination($tagIds);

$images = $this->image_pagination($tagIds);
```

which add the limiting conditions to `$paginate` and look like this:

```
private function post_pagination($tags, $page = 1) {
    $this->paginate['PostsTag']['conditions'] = array(
        "status" => 1,
        "OR" => array("tag_id" => $tags)
    );
    $this->paginate['PostsTag']['page'] = $page;
    return $this->paginate("PostsTag");
}

private function image_pagination($tags, $page = 1) {
    $this->paginate['ImagesTag']['conditions'] = array(
        "gallery" => 1,
        "OR" => array("tag_id" => $tags)
    );
    $this->paginate['ImagesTag']['page'] = $page;
    return $this->paginate("ImagesTag");
}
```

Cake is respecting `limit`, `order`, `contain`, etc. without issue, but drops the ball on `conditions` specifically for whichever model I try to paginate over second. It feeds me back the first 4 results ordered properly, but completely unfiltered. I do not think my somewhat complicated `conditions` are at fault either -- as long as I don't break syntax, I can type completely random strings into `conditions` for the second `paginate()` and get back identical results.

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

[edit] Here is an SQL dump of the second `paginate()` query:

```
SELECT `PostsTag`.`id`, `PostsTag`.`post_id`, `PostsTag`.`tag_id`, 
`Tag`.`id`, `Tag`.`name`, `Post`.`id`, `Post`.`title`, `Post`.`created` 
FROM `posts_tags` AS `PostsTag` 
LEFT JOIN `tags` AS `Tag` ON (`PostsTag`.`tag_id` = `Tag`.`id`) 
LEFT JOIN `posts` AS `Post` ON (`PostsTag`.`post_id` = `Post`.`id`) 
WHERE 1 = 1 
GROUP BY `Post`.`id` 
ORDER BY `Post`.`id` 
DESC LIMIT 4
```

As you can see, Cake is generating a `WHERE 1 = 1` in place of my conditions.

Comment: Have you tried using `'Model.field' => val` in your condition array instead of just `'field' => val`? So like `PostTag.status` etc.

Comment: You know, in my bleary-eyed exhaustion the other night I didn't even notice that I had neglected to specify models for some of those conditions, so thank you for bringing that to my attention. However, the problem persists. Right now I have just assembled a straight SQL query manually for the second paginate(), which is working fine. Though the problem I had still confuses me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So upon some more poking around I discovered the following:

Any alterations made to `$paginate` after an initial `paginate()` call is made are not carried through to the `Paginator` component. This applies to `conditions`, `order`, `limit`, etc.

So doing this:

```
$this->paginate['<model1>']['conditions'] = array( ... );
$model1Results = $this->paginate("<model1>");

$this->paginate['<model2>']['conditions'] = array( ... );
$model2Results = $this->paginate("<model2>");
```

Will return results for `<model1>` that obey the new conditions/order/limit/whatever you've applied, but your results for `<model2>` will be based on the original conditions defined for it in `$paginate`. Your controller will see the updates to `$paginate` just fine, but it appears `$paginate` can only be grabbed by `Paginator` once.

The workaround I have found is to make any and all changes to `$paginate` BEFORE the first `paginate()` call, so:

```
$this->paginate['<model1>']['conditions'] = array( ... );
$this->paginate['<model2>']['conditions'] = array( ... );

$model1Results = $this->paginate('<model1>');
$model2Results = $this->paginate('<model2>');
```

I've been poking around in `PaginatorComponent.php` to figure out why things work this way, and any further insight would, of course, be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

DEAR PEOPLE FROM THE FUTURE: Here's what we've figured out so far...

OP is correct that `YourController::$paginate` is only fed into the `PaginatorComponent` once. If you need to call `YourController::paginate()` again with different options, you'll need to unload the component first, e.g.:

```
$this->Components->unload('Paginator');
```

Then, the next time you call `YourController::paginate()`, it will reload whatever's in the `YourController::$paginate` property.